# Tablesorter jQuery wont sort my table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablesorter

I am trying to work with Tablesorter but it doesn't seem to work when I output the table using PHP.

My PHP code:

```
function displayHours() {
    include 'dbinfo.php';
    global $name;
    $date = $_SESSION["selectedDate"];
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM hours WHERE name='$name' AND date='$date'");
    echo '<thead><tr>
    <th><center>Project name</th>
    <th><center>Hour(s)</th>
    </tr></thead>';
    $color = FALSE;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      if (!$color) {
        echo "<tbody><tr>";
      $color = TRUE;
      } else if ($color) {
        echo "<tbody><tr class=\"alt\">";
        $color = FALSE;
      }
    echo "<td> " . $row['projectName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td> " . $row['description'] . "</td>";
    echo '</tr> ';
    echo '</tbody>';
    }
}
```

My html code:

```
<div class="datagrid">
    <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">  
        <?php displayHours();?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

My jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
});
```

If I output two  in one loop it at least sorts them, but once I only make it one  it wont do anything.

I tried everything, any help please?

Comment: you are adding `tbody` to all of your rows, this could be the problem. Instead of adding every row you should open the tag before loop and close it after loop. Besides you have closed tbody where you run displayHours fonction.

Comment: Wow.. it worked actually. I totally forgot that it would give a tdbody to every row... Thanks a lot!!! Saved my day.

Comment: Please tell me this is never _ever_ going to be production facing code? The PHP code is riddled with injection attack vectors :|

Comment: @scriptmonster add your comment as an answer, and I'll upvote it!

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with the `tablesorter`, but your table html. You PHP code generates `thead` and several `tbody` tags. Normally there should be one `tbody` tag.

To fix that in your PHP before your while loop in put `tbody` opening and after your loop close the tag.

```
//open tbody tag
echo "<tbody>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    //print rows
}

//close tbody tag
echo "</tbody>";
```

There is also an unnecessary `tbody` closing in your "html code", it's better to remove it.

```
<div class="datagrid">
    <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">  
        <?php displayHours();?>
    </table>
</div>
```

Then your tablesorter would be working smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I know while using tablesorter myself. I had to use 
$(table).trigger("update")
to get a dynamically added table to update, however this wasn't with php.